# get clicked date from full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Clicking a date on [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)  launches a modal '#view_event'. I want to get the date on which I have clicked. each date has the class '.fc-day' has an attribute data-date="2015-02-13". so I tried the following.

```
$(".fc-day").click(function(){
    var fetchDate = $(this).data("date");
    $("#displayDate").text(fetchDate);
});
```

'#displayDate' is a p element in the modal. The above code isn't working. What's wrong?

Comment: are you able to alert fetchDate?

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work either.

Comment: try this code http://jsfiddle.net/9m443p1o/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use the `classes` to access the date. there are ways to get the date and below  is one where you can do it when you initialize the calendar ,
Using that you can get the `date` , `month` and `year`  separately.

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
            alert('Clicked on: ' + date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear());  
        },

    });
```

Comment: How can I know the date of it with out click the day? @prime

Comment: @saraadly : dayClick  will  get you the date of  the  clicked item. But without clicking which date you want to fetch ? Which date you want to know ?

Comment: @prime Where can I possibly insert this in a blade file. I have currently inserted your code in script tag below my codes in blade php but is not working. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: @EemJee Not sure what is the issue. Can you share your code or post a new Question and tag me.

Comment: @prime I am working on fullcalendar v4 and I am not using jQuery, how can I get clicked date?

Comment: @NathanTM did you try this way mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @prime I am using V4 without jQuery but I found out the solution from the documentation. There is 'dateClick' callback which does that for V4 - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use 'select' in fullcalendar

```
o.fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
    },
    select: 
      function(start,end){ 
          alert(start); 
          alert(end); 
          // var selDate = new Date(start);
          // add your function
    },
    editable: false
});
```

[fullcalendar/select](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/)

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar provide default event to get selected date and time. So don't need to use any extra thing.Only you need to use below code snippet and you will get selected date in full calendar. It will be UTC format so you have to make some processing to get that date as per your timezone

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
     dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
         alert("Selected Date:"+date._d)
      }
  });
```

please give your feedback if you find this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/handlers

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log('clicked on ' + date.format());
}
```